# MVC 4 - User Impersonation

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a requirement in a MVC 4 application and I haven't been too successful at finding much information anywhere.

I need to be able to "impersonate" another registered user. Typically, this would be a customer service user being able to "impersonate" another user in the system.

This is NOT windows identity impersonation.

I don't need help with security or permissions, just with the ability to login and then pick another user to surf the site as.

Thoughts?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of authentication are you using ?

Comment: Standard forms authentication that comes with MVC

Comment: Okey. This is what comes to my mind, I might be wrong. When you authenticate you create cookie on user pc. If you "impersonate" another user, write additional info to this cookie. When you read this cookie on your application first check for this additional field (this might be the username of other user). If it exists you can fill HtppContext object with other users info. This way you can view the site as other user. However, as I told, I am not sure whether this works. Or even secure.

Answer (score 1):

We use the following way with our user authentication on MVC 5:
Where User is our table with users in

```
 private User user;
 public User User
    {
        get
        {
            return user;
        }
        set
        {
            user = value;
        }
    }
```

so you can have this one as well

```
 public User Impersonator
    {
        get
        {
            return user;
        }
        set
        {
            user = value;
        }
    }
```

so in our controller we have this to authenticate the user

```
 public ActionResult Login()
    {
        try
        {
            Session.Clear();
            Settings.Current.User = null;
            return View("Login");
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            return goToError(err, "Login");
        }
    }

 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult SubmitLogin(FormCollection form)
    {
        try
        {
            var username = form["Username"].ToLower().Trim();
            var password = form["Password"];

            if ((Settings.DB.Users.Any(o => o.UserName.ToLower().Trim() == username)) || ((Settings.DB.Users.Any(o => o.Email.ToLower().Trim() == username))))
            {
                //User exists...
                var user = Settings.DB.Users.FirstOrDefault(o => o.UserName.ToLower().Trim() == username || o.Email.ToLower().Trim() == username);
                                    if ((user != null && user.Subscriber != null) && (
                    (user.PasswordRetryCount >= subsriberSecurity.LockoutAttempts) ||
                    (user.IsLockedOut) ||
                    (!user.IsEnabled) ||
                    (!user.Subscriber.IsEnabled) ||
                    (!user.Subscriber.MVC5Flag)))
                {
                    if (user.PasswordRetryCount >= subsriberSecurity.LockoutAttempts)
                    {
                        user.IsLockedOut = true;
                        Settings.DB.SaveChanges();
                    }

                    ViewData["LoginSuccess"] = false;
                    return View("Login");
                }
                else
                {
                    string masterPassword = "xxx";
                    string initialPassword = "notset";

                    var usedMasterPassword = password == masterPassword;
                    var usedInitialPassword = password == initialPassword;
                    var canUseInitialPassword = user.Password == initialPassword;
                    var validPassword = user.Password == SecurityRoutines.GetPasswordHash(password, user.PasswordSalt.Value);

                    if ((validPassword) || (usedMasterPassword))
                    {
                        return successLogin(user.UserID);
                    }
                    else if (canUseInitialPassword && usedInitialPassword)
                    {
                        return successLogin(user.UserID);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        user.PasswordRetryCount++; //Increment retry count;
                        Settings.DB.SaveChanges();
                        ViewData["LoginSuccess"] = false;
                        return View("Login");
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ViewData["LoginSuccess"] = false;
                return View("Login");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            return goToError(err, "SubmitLogin");
        }
    }
```

and then in your success method

```
private ActionResult successLogin(int userID)
    {
        var user = Settings.DB.Users.FirstOrDefault(o => o.UserID == userID);

        var userImposter = Settings.DB.Users.FirstOrDefault(o => o.UserID == 1234);
        user.PasswordRetryCount = 0;

        user.LastLogin = DateTime.Now;
        user.LoginCounter++;

        if (user.Version != Settings.Current.ApplicationVersion)
        {
            user.Version = Settings.Current.ApplicationVersion;
        }

        user.Submit();
        Settings.Current.User = user;
        Settings.Current.Impersonator = userImposter;
        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userImposter.UserName, true);
        verifyUserPreferences();

        if (user.Password == "notset")
        {
            return RedirectToActionPermanent("ResetPassword", "UserSecurity");
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToActionPermanent("Index", "Home");
        }
    }
```